# Android : Espresso UI testing, what is the right approach to test classes structure?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm trying to start with automatization testing of the UI in Android APP. I choosed espresso FW for this and i would like to ask on this:

What is the right structure of the test classes? It means, should i create a new testClass for each activity and run all in batch or i should have testing class for some scenarios across the whole app?

And how can i run all tests in package at once? Because now i must right-click on the test class and select run test class manually for each test.

Thanks for any advice.

**Note:**

Example of the very simple scenario i did by this way:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void buttonShouldUpdateText(){
        onView(withId(R.id.goToSecondActivityBtn)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.text1SecondView)).check(matches(withText("Hello world!")));
        onView(withId(R.id.txtFieldOne)).perform(typeText("TEST"));
    }

}
```

But if i addded second method into class which is processing some interaction on the second activity i failed with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

To run all tests (assuming you have a Gradle configuration) use the Gradle task **connectedCheck**.

In Android Studio you can select it from the gradle tasks list on your right panel and from command line:

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

As for testing structure, assume in your example test class that every @Test method restarts your activity (in the example MainActivity). If you really want to test only the second Activity you should create a new test class, even if it's just to organize test cases in a cleaner way.

For a more advanced test architecture using Espresso I recommend this article:
https://medium.com/@neoranga55/the-evolution-journey-of-android-gui-testing-f65005f7ced8

And the demo code:
https://github.com/neoranga55/CleanGUITestArchitecture